# Can we increase the font size in shippo generated label (Shippo label api)?

Tags: shippo

I want to edit the text size using api on shippo generated label. **Is there any way to increase the text size or make text bold?**

I'm specifically looking at the Shipment, Transaction Create API call. ([Shippo Api Reference](https://goshippo.com/docs/reference#transaction-create))

Answer (score 0):

The label image data returned by Shippo come back from the carrier APIs themselves. You could do is modify the ZPL returned to change the font, but you really shouldn't be changing the carrier-approved labeling. https://www.zebra.com/us/en/support-downloads/knowledge-articles/zpl-command-information-and-details.html